# Making argument parsing more streamlined and readable than if-statements

Tags: python, design-patterns, parsing

I am working on an API wrapper for calls to a website. Each of several types of calls can take a large number of optional arguments, some of which contradict. In the interest of preventing the user from supplying incompatible parameters, I would like to verify that the arguments are correct before submitting the request.

However, the simplest technique to do so has resulted in the below nightmare, with several if-statements. I know this is not a best practice, but I am unsure what the best method to correct it would be. I know that using *kwargs would probably be involved, but I don't see how that would save me from verifying the arguments in much the same way as below. I have heard that I should probably wrap the arguments in a class, but I'm unsure how much of a better idea that is.

````
def list_tag_alias(
        self,
        name_matches: str = None,
        status: str = None,
        order: str = None,
        antecedent_tag: int = None,
        consequent_tag: int = None,
        limit: int = None,
        before_page: int = None,
        after_page: int = None,
        page: int = None,
    ):
        query_url = "tag_aliases.json?"
        arguments = []
        if name_matches != None:
            arguments.append("search[name_matches]={}".format(name_matches))
        if status != None:
            assert status.lower() in (
                "approved",
                "active",
                "pending",
                "deleted",
                "retired",
                "processing",
                "queued",
                "blank",
            ), "status must be one of: approved, active, pending, deleted, retired, processing, queued, or blank."
            arguments.append("search[status]={}".format(status.lower()))
        if order != None:
            assert order.lower() in (
                "status",
                "created_at",
                "updated_at",
                "name",
                "tag_count",
            ), "order must be one of status, created_at, updated_at, name, tag_count"
            arguments.append("search[order]={}".format(order.lower()))
        if antecedent_tag != None:
            assert 0 <= antecedent_tag <= 8
            arguments.append(
                "search[antecedent_tag][category]={}".format(str(antecedent_tag))
            )
        if consequent_tag != None:
            assert 0 <= consequent_tag <= 8
            arguments.append(
                "search[consequent_tag][category]={}".format(str(consequent_tag))
            )
        if limit != None:
            assert 0 <= limit <= 1000, "limit must be between 0 and 1000, inclusive"
            arguments.append("limit={}".format(str(limit)))
        if before_page != None:
            assert (
                after_page == None and page == None
            ), "only one of before_page, after_page, or page must be supplied."
            assert before_page >= 0, "before_page must be greater than 0"
            arguments.append("page=b{}".format(str(before_page)))
        if after_page != None:
            assert (
                before_page == None and page == None
            ), "only one of before_page, after_page, or page must be supplied."
            assert after_page >= 0, "after_page must be greater than 0"
            arguments.append("page=a{}".format(str(after_page)))
        if page != None:
            assert (
                before_page == None and after_page == None
            ), "only one of before_page, after_page, or page must be supplied."
            arguments.append("page={}".format(str(page)))

        query_url += "&".join(arguments)

        request = WebRequest(state_info=self.state_info)
        response = request.submit_request(query_url=query_url)
        return response.json()
```
````

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Don't assert; raise exceptions

`assert` statements may be disabled by [flag](https://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-O) (`python -O ...`) or [environment variable](https://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONOPTIMIZE).

Use `raise ValueError("status must be one of: approved...")` instead.

## Don't test for equality with None

`None` is a singleton value.  You should use `status is not None` instead of `status != None`.

You can just test the value directly, `None` is a false value.  So `if status:` can be used instead of `if status != None:` or `if status is not None:`.  Note: that other things test as false, such as `0`, `""`, and `[]`, so this test is not exactly the same.

## Use enums

Strings are hard to use.  Should you pass `"delete"`, `"deleted"`, or `"deleting"`, ... or maybe `"removed"`?

Enumerations give you named constants to use.  Your IDE may even help you autocomplete the constant name.

```
from enum import Enum

class Status(Enum):
    APPROVED = "approved"
    ACTIVE = "active"
    ...

...
            if status:
                arguments.append("search[status]={}".format(status.value))
```

You can turn strings into enums like:

```
            if status is not None and not isinstance(status, Status):
                status = Status(status.lower())
```

So the caller could pass in `"deleted"` or `"DELETED"` or `Status.DELETED` and they would all work, but if they passed in `"removed"`, you'd get a `ValueError: 'removed' is not a valid Status` exception.  So you no longer have to manually test if the given `status` is a legal status word.  (However, if not every status word is legal in a function, these would still need to be tested.)

## Common functions

If you have several functions which take `before_page`, `after_page` and `page` arguments, you probably have the same validation requirements in each.  You should call another method to validate these, something like:

```
            self._validate_pages(before_page, after_page, page, arguments)
```

## Positional & keyword-only arguments

As it stands, a caller may try call `obj.list_tag_alias(None, None, "approved")` to list the approved tag aliases.  But actually, that used `"approved"` as the `order` parameter; while `status` is the 3th argument, that includes `self` in the count.

The correct call would be either `obj.list_tag_alias(None, "approved")`, or better, `obj.list_tag_alias(status="approved")`.

You can deny the positional argument variant by forcing the parameters to be keyword-only parameters, by adding a `*` to the argument list:

```
def list_tag_alias(
    self,
    name_matches: str = None,
    *,                         # remaining parameters are keyword-only
    status: str = None,
    order: str = None,
    ...
```

Now you can call `obj.list_tag_alias("fred")` or `obj.list_tag_alias(status="approved")`, but `obj.list_tag_alias(None, "approved")` is an error:

```
TypeError: list_tag_alias() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

## Argument dictionary

```
    arguments = []
    ...
        arguments.append("search[name_matches]={}".format(name_matches))
    ...
    query_url += "&".join(arguments)
```

You are using `"...={}".format(...)` and `.append()` multiple times to create your argument list to produce the query string.  Consider using a dictionary instead:

```
    arguments = {}
    ...
        arguments["search[name_matches]"] = name_matches
    ...
    query_url += "&".join(f"{key}={value}" for key, value in arguments.items())
```

Bonus: using `f"...{value}"` is interpolating the value into a string, so `str()` calls for limit, tag, and page parameters are unnecessary.